# How to plan Mavic Mini flight using ios/android app?

Tags: dji, long-range-drone, dji-mavic-mini, smartphone-app

I want to create plan (automate) for my Mavic Mini (1) drone using phone app. I want to move my drone in both x and y axis. So, it should gain some height, then move ahead and then again getting low again and some forward/backward movement. This is my requirement. I tried to find solution but no simple straight answer.

(IOS apps are expensive but if any app confirms that I can also lower down height and increase height, basically y axis then also I am good to buy that app.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [Litchi is compatible with a Mavic Mini 1](https://flylitchi.com/help).  With Litchi you can set waypoints to which your drone will move to, you can set altitudes, drone angles, camera angles, etc,then capture images or video.  Litchi is a low cost ($24.99) software solution for both iOS and Android.